How to do quantum tomography on a subsystem of 2 of 30 qubits in cirq?
I have a 30 qubit system and I need to do quantum tomography on a subsystem of 2 of its qubit. How can I do this in Cirq?

State tomography is implemented in Cirq as
cirq.experiments.state_tomography(
    sampler: 'cirq.Sampler',
    qubits: Sequence['cirq.Qid'],
    circuit: 'cirq.Circuit',
    repetitions: int = 1000,
    prerotations: Optional[Sequence[Tuple[float, float]]] = None,
)

https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/3b975b093afa80969731af85002634a6f2ce8270/cirq-core/cirq/experiments/n_qubit_tomography.py#L132-L160
e.g.
cirq.experiments.state_tomography(cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator(noise=noise_model), qubits=..., circuit=...)


Thanks for this. But does this specifically select n out of the whole qubits from the output and do the QST? Suppose I have 30 qubits and I just need to do QST on 3 of it.

Hi, I have tried this code and it's not running, basically,
cirq.experiments.state_tomography(cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator(noise=cirq.ConstantQubitNoiseModel(cirq.depolarize(0.01))), qubits, circuit)

cirq.experiments.state_tomography(cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator(noise=cirq.ConstantQubitNoiseModel(cirq.depolarize(0.01))), q, circuit)
This is not running in Google Colab

I'm guessing that q above stands for one qubit, right? ... the method expects a list of qubits so [q] should fix your issue
>> cirq.experiments.state_tomography(cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator(noise=cirq.ConstantQubitNoiseModel(cirq.depolarize(0.01))), [q], circuit)
<cirq.experiments.qubit_characterizations.TomographyResult at 0x7e331c4329e0>


Hi, this one is actually giving me negative eigenvalues for the density matrix which shoud'nt happen as as the desnity matrix is positive semi-definite

You only need to do State Tomography on the 2 qubits. But take in mind that, when you perform that, you trace out the other qubits, and are taken as ancilla.

Could you help me with the cirq code?
